# Convergence in probability exercise

Tags: self-study, convergence

I have to solve the following exercise:

> Let $X_1,X_2,…,X_n,…$ be a sequence of random variables, with $X_n \sim \text{Uniform}(0,n)$.  Also, consider $Y_n= e^{-X_n}$. Does the second sequence converge in probability? If yes, what is its limit?

My brief answer would be no, because as $n$ tends to infinity $X_n$ tends to $0$, while $Y_n$ tends to $1$. Am I right or am I missing something?  Any help will be great (I am an undergraduate student).

Comment: For self-study questions, we prefer to see what you have tried and where you are stuck.  Can you explain why you believe the convergence you postulate would hold?

Comment: Why would $X_n$ converge to $0$ or $Y_n$ to $1$?

Comment: If $X_n$ tended to $0$ in probability then certainly $\Pr(|X_n|\le 1)$ would tend to $1.$  But $\Pr(|X_n|\le 1)=1/n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty,$ demonstrating $X_n$ cannot tend to $0.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For the convergence for $X_n$ have a think about the expected value of this quantity and see if it matches your postulated limit.  For the convergence of $Y_n$, it should be possible for you to get an explicit form for the probability $\mathbb{P}(Y_n \geqslant \varepsilon)$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.  See if you can write this probability as a function of $n$ and then see what happens to it as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your hint.
The following is my reasoning:
By definition, $Y_n$ converge to $X_n$ if  $lim(n→∞)⁡(P(|Y_n - X_n |≥ ε)=0$, for every ε > 0.
The values of $X_n$ are given by 1⁄n, therefore: $lim(n→∞)⁡(P(|e^(-1⁄n)  – 1⁄n| ≥ ε)=   lim(n→∞)⁡(P(|e^(-1⁄n) | ≥ ε) ≠ 0$ because as n increases, the value of $Y_n$ tends towards 1.
Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is wrong.  You do not seem to be following the uniform distribution given in your question.